# How to turn off XREF comments in Ghidra's disassembly view?

Tags: disassembly, ghidra

Sometimes a function will have a series of XREF comments next to it in the disassembly view such as in the following example:

```
                     **************************************************************
                     *                          FUNCTION                          *
                     **************************************************************
                     void __stdcall FUN_803adb50(void)
                       assume GQR0 = 0x0
                       assume GQR1 = 0x0
                       assume GQR2 = 0x40004
                       assume GQR3 = 0x50005
                       assume GQR4 = 0x60006
                       assume GQR5 = 0x70007
                       assume GQR6 = 0x0
                       assume GQR7 = 0x0
                       assume r13 = 0x805dd0e0
                       assume r2 = 0x805e6700
     void              <VOID>         <RETURN>
                     FUN_803adb50                                    XREF[357]:   FUN_80058564:80058574(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_80058a80:80058a90(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_8005c298:8005c2a8(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_80288c48:80288c58(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_802b0ab8:802b0ac8(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_802b3860:802b3870(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_802b3a4c:802b3a5c(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_802b4f94:802b4fa4(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_802b563c:802b564c(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_802c81cc:802c81dc(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_802ca894:802ca8a4(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_802cd8f0:802cd908(c), 
                                                                                  AnimationTreeSomething:802d1ff8(
                                                                                  FUN_8040fd5c:8040fd6c(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_80418708:80418718(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_8041e46c:8041e47c(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_80444fe0:80444ff0(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_80445cf4:80445d04(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_80446d80:80446d90(c), 
                                                                                  FUN_8044c500:8044c510(c), [more]
```

How can I turn these off (and on)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just press the `Edit the listing fields` button

[image]

Then go to the `Instruction/Data` section

[image]

Right-click on `XRef Header` and `XRef` and from the menu choose `Disable field`.